# How to write a python script in Re-Dash?

Tags: python, dashboard, redash

I have already edited the .env file and added the export 
REDASH_ADDITIONAL_QUERY_RUNNERS=redash.query_runner.python into it

I have python as a datasource now. But I'm not sure how to write python
code to be executed under a query after selecting the python as the datasource.

https://gist.github.com/arikfr/be7c2888520c44cf4f0f#file-query-py-L11

I've been following that example to structure my code. But I can't even get a simple script to run because I'm getting this error

Error running query: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'annotate_query'

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the error message, it looks like the Celery worker didn't load the Python query runner.

To restart the workers just run:

`$ supervisorctl restart all`

Comment: That fixed it ! Thanks !